# What do values only in JS map mean and how to write it the long way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that only passing values of an object to JS map function results in having the objects values as variables (works just fine)

```js
{links.map(({ key, href, label }) => (
   <li key={key}>
     <Link href={href} />
   </li>
))}
```

but how does it actually look like when I want to write it without syntactic sugar?

My attempt so far

```js
{links.map(link => ({ key = link.key, href = link.href }) => (
  <li key={key}>
    <Link href={href} />
  </li>
))}
```

but with the latter I'm getting:

```js
Functions are not valid as a React child
```

I need to know how to deconstruct the syntactic sugar example because I have a nested object and I need to iterate through each of the nesting.

Comment: the first example throws an error?

Comment: @Sagivb.g not at all

Comment: So what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Sagivb.g I need to have nested mapping and I want to understand how the long version of this syntactic suger looks like.

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to achieve. These two snippets are totally different. Do you mean `{links.map(link => (
   <li key={link.key}> ...` by 'long version'?

Comment: @estus I want to iterate through a nested object and return a component of nested values. So how does the first function apply for a nested object like this:
`const links = [{ label: 'one', sublinks: [{ href: "/hello", label: "hello" }, {..} }]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example returns an anonymous function on each iteration.

I think you wanted to do this:

```
{links.map(link => (
  <li key={link.key}>
    <Link href={link.href} />
  </li>
))}
```

**Edit**
Not sure what you realy want to do with nested objects.
But as per your example, here is a running code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    links: [
      {
        key: 'one',
        href: '/some-url',
        sublinks: [{
          href: "/hello",
          label: "hello"
        }]
      },
      {
        key: 'two',
        href: '/some-url2',
        sublinks: []
      }
    ]
  }
  render() {
    const { links } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {links.map(link => (
          <div>
            <a href={link.href}>{link.key}</a>
            {link.sublinks &&
              link.sublinks.map(subLink => (
                <div>
                  <a href={subLink.href}>{subLink.label}</a>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Dang! Thank you very much!

Comment: How does this work in a nested object like this: `const links = [{ key: 'one', href: '/some-url', sublinks: [{ href: "/hello", label: "hello" }, {..} }]` so that I can access sublinks too

Comment: You got what I meant! But why is `link.sublinks &&` needed, can I not omit that?

Comment: This is just checking that it is not `null` or `undefined` see [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Right! One last thing though, I wanna pass all values to a component like this: https://pastebin.com/9qr2kRXT is that valid or would you write it differently? If so you can amend? This works btw :)

Answer (score 1):

I see you accepted an answer for the original question. In response to your question about handling sub links, take a look at this way. It supports multiple levels of sub links without having to repeat any code. This is useful if you don't know how many levels there are, for example in a menu or navigation.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e4o8pscL/)

The TreeList component:

```
const TreeList = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.links.map(link => (
        <li key={link.key}>
          <Link href={link.href} label={link.label} />
          {link.sublinks ? <TreeList links={link.sublinks}></TreeList> : null}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const links = [{ key:4, label: 'top', href: '/some-url'}, { key:1, label: 'one', href: '/some-url', sublinks: [{ key:2, href: "/hello", label: "hello", sublinks: [{ key:3, href: "/hello", label: "grandchild" }] }]} ];

    return <TreeList links={links}></TreeList>;
  }
}
```

Comment: oh so you're saying I can pass in the component in itself?